# Center several divs in a parent div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have some divs that I want to center in a horizontal row. I've tried everything I can think of and researched it with no avail. Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
        <!--references-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id = "box">
                    <h1 id="head">Hello, World</h1>
                    <div id = "btn-panel">
                        <button class="btn" id="btn1">panel1</button>
                        <button class="btn" id="btn2">panel2</button>
                        <button class="btn" id="btn3">panel3</button>
                        <button class="btn" id="btn4">panel4</button>
                    </div><!--button-panel-->
                </div> <!--Box-->
                        <div id = "panel-row">
                            <div class="panel" id="p1"><p class="phead">Panel#1</p><hr></div>
                            <div class="panel" id="p2"><p class="phead">Panel#2</p><hr></div>
                            <div class="panel" id="p3"><p class="phead">Panel#3</p><hr></div>
                            <div class="panel" id="p4"><p class="phead">Panel#4</p><hr></div>
                        </div><!--panel-row-->
            </div> <!--wrapper-->
        </body>
    <script src="js/Index.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
   font-weight: 300; 
   margin: 0px;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#box { 
    background-color: #EEE;
    Width: 100%;
    Height: 250px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    Text-align: center; 
}

#head {
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-size: 20pt;
}
#btn-panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#panel-row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.panel {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #7FFFD4;
}
.phead {
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    margin-left: 20px; 
}

#panel-row {
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-left: auto;  
}
```

any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Dylan, are looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/grGKWZ

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1:** (Recommended)

*Using flexbox.*

Achieving this is quite easy using flexbox, what you need to do is set `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` in your parent element.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#box {
  background-color: #EEE;
  Width: 100%;
  Height: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  Text-align: center;
}
#head {
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
#btn-panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#panel-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #7FFFD4;
}
.phead {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box">
    <h1 id="head">Hello, World</h1>
    <div id="btn-panel">
      <button class="btn" id="btn1">panel1</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn2">panel2</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn3">panel3</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn4">panel4</button>
    </div>
    <!--button-panel-->
  </div>
  <!--Box-->
  <div id="panel-row">
    <div class="panel" id="p1">
      <p class="phead">Panel#1</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="p2">
      <p class="phead">Panel#2</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="p3">
      <p class="phead">Panel#3</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="p4">
      <p class="phead">Panel#4</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--panel-row-->
</div>
<!--wrapper-->
```

---

**SOLUTION 2:**

*Using text-center for `inline-block` elements.*

Probably the *simplest* solution for your demo, which will **only work with `inline-block` elements**, is using the css property `text-align: center;` in your parent element and `text-align: initial;` in your child elements.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#box {
  background-color: #EEE;
  Width: 100%;
  Height: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  Text-align: center;
}
#head {
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
#btn-panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#panel-row {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.panel {
  text-align: initial;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #7FFFD4;
}
.phead {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box">
    <h1 id="head">Hello, World</h1>
    <div id="btn-panel">
      <button class="btn" id="btn1">panel1</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn2">panel2</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn3">panel3</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn4">panel4</button>
    </div>
    <!--button-panel-->
  </div>
  <!--Box-->
  <div id="panel-row">
    <div class="panel" id="p1">
      <p class="phead">Panel#1</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="p2">
      <p class="phead">Panel#2</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="p3">
      <p class="phead">Panel#3</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="p4">
      <p class="phead">Panel#4</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--panel-row-->
</div>
<!--wrapper-->
```

---

**SOLUTION 3:**

*Using fixed width.*

In order for the `margin: 0 auto;` *trick* to work, you need to set a width to the element.

This is **hard to maintain** since your child elements' width can change and you would need to change the parent's width, not mentioning the responsiveness issues this can cause, which will most probably need media queries to be solved.

```css
body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#box {
  background-color: #EEE;
  Width: 100%;
  Height: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  Text-align: center;
}
#head {
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
#btn-panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#panel-row {
  width: 522px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #7FFFD4;
}
.phead {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box">
    <h1 id="head">Hello, World</h1>
    <div id="btn-panel">
      <button class="btn" id="btn1">panel1</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn2">panel2</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn3">panel3</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn4">panel4</button>
    </div>
    <!--button-panel-->
  </div>
  <!--Box-->
  <div id="panel-row">
    <div class="panel" id="p1">
      <p class="phead">Panel#1</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="p2">
      <p class="phead">Panel#2</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="p3">
      <p class="phead">Panel#3</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="p4">
      <p class="phead">Panel#4</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--panel-row-->
</div>
<!--wrapper-->
```

---

**OBSERVATIONS:**

- The `#panel-row` selector is repeated in your css.
- You do not need to add the css property `width: 100%` to a block level element, this is the default width.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, You must center with **text-align: center;** since the .panels are inline like text or spans.

```
#panel-row {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#panel-row, .panel, .phead {
  text-align:center;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/grGKWZ

Answer (score 0):

You could use `text-align: center` on the `#panel-row`

```css
    body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
   font-weight: 300; 
   margin: 0px;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#box { 
    background-color: #EEE;
    Width: 100%;
    Height: 250px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    Text-align: center; 
}

#head {
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-size: 20pt;
}
#btn-panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#panel-row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center; /* Align text inside panel row*/
}

.panel {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #7FFFD4;
}
.phead {
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    /*margin-left: 20px*/ /* this margin is messing up with centered-text alignment*/
}

#panel-row {
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-left: auto;  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
        <!--references-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id = "box">
                    <h1 id="head">Hello, World</h1>
                    <div id = "btn-panel">
                        <button class="btn" id="btn1">panel1</button>
                        <button class="btn" id="btn2">panel2</button>
                        <button class="btn" id="btn3">panel3</button>
                        <button class="btn" id="btn4">panel4</button>
                    </div><!--button-panel-->
                </div> <!--Box-->
                        <div id = "panel-row">
                            <div class="panel" id="p1"><p class="phead">Panel#1</p><hr></div>
                            <div class="panel" id="p2"><p class="phead">Panel#2</p><hr></div>
                            <div class="panel" id="p3"><p class="phead">Panel#3</p><hr></div>
                            <div class="panel" id="p4"><p class="phead">Panel#4</p><hr></div>
                        </div><!--panel-row-->
            </div> <!--wrapper-->
        </body>
    <script src="js/Index.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
</html>
```